# Ensure popup is fully visible on mapbox-gl map

Tags: mapbox-gl

I have noticed when the size of the popup on a mapbox-gl map is larger than 50% of the height of the map, if the anchor is unset and the marker is just below the middle of the map, the popup will open below the marker and a portion of the popup will extend off the map and not be visible. Is there any way around this? i.e. is it possible to get the popup to open to the side or even over the popup in this case?